# Bibliography is not aligned

Tags: natbib, mendeley

I am using overleaf to write up my thesis. The work is almost done, yet I have a problem with my bibliography:
[image]

As you can see, the 25th entry just pops to the left without any reason. Through rearrangement, I noticed that this would follow with any entry below 25 in this page. I tried different citations for the same work; the entry would simply disappear and an empty entry would appear for the first reference.

I have generated these entries using Mendeley. I leave a copy of this entry below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 @book{Murphy2012,
address = {Cambridge, Massachusetts},
author = {Murphy, Kevin},
isbn = {9780262018029},
publisher = {The MIT Press},
title = {{Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective}},
year = {2012}
}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome to the site, (2) please provide a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is, as we know nothing about your document we have no idea what is wrong. Does this document compile without errors in Overleaf?

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't provided nearly enough information so far for anyone to be able to offer a diagnosis of what ails your document, let alone a conjecture a cure. Please provide a [Minimally Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. In particular, please be sure to state which document class and (assuming you use a software tool to create the bibliography) which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Please show us your used bib entry for Jonas Mockus, number 24 too.

Comment: My guess would be an unescaped special character in the DOI of [24] (Mockus). One solution would be to escape that character (probably a `_`), but a much better solution would be to tell your bibliography style to use an appropriate macro to typeset the DOI that automatically escapes `_`. How that is done will depend on the bibliography style you use. (Please tell us which bibliography packages you load and which style you use. You tagged the question `biblatex`, but usually `biblatex` has no problems with tricky DOIs.)

Comment: Any news here? As the question stands now we can sort of guess what might be the problem, but the best solution definitely depends on your bibliography setup (the bibliography packages you load and the style you use). We can only help you properly if you share a short example document with us that reproduces the problem, a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. If there is no development here in due time I will vote to close the question.

Comment: Dear moewe you were right! The problem was exactly the "_" character in the DOI. I tried changing package that manages my bibliography (I use {natbib} and  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}), but the whole thing crashed :/ I ended up making with uploading the zip file into a new project and just removed the DOI.
My deadline is tomorrow and I won't change this. But maybe you can explain further for others who might face the same problem.
In any case, thanks heaps for  the help.

Comment: A good answer here depends on more than just the info about `natbib`, so if you resolved your problem and are no loger interested in an answer it might be better to close the question than to try and answer it with not enough data available.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments